# ImageView won't showing bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

We want to put a **bitmap** ( element in setView) in a `ImageView` and display it. We have no errors its simply a black background when we run the app.

```
 public void setView(View element) {
    mainView = element;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setContentView(element);
    try {
        rootLayout.addView(mainView,layoutParams);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is our **onCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getInstance();
    this.authService = new AuthenticationService();
    this.authService.getInstance(this);

    this.settingsManager = SettingsManager.getInstance();
    this.statusManager = StatusManager.getInstance();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mainView = findViewById(R.id.mainContentView);
    loadingView = null;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) AuthenticationService.getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vs = (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) vs.findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);

    AsyncCallRegistrationWS task = new AsyncCallRegistrationWS();
    task.execute();
}
```

We have tried every suggested solution to this problem on stackoverflow but nothing worked for us.

EDIT:

We call the setView() in another Class

```
public void createDisplay(){
    creationDate = DateTime.now();
    try {
        if (state == DisplayState.Validated){
            if (entry != null && entry.template != null){
                DateTime now = DateTime.now();

                if (SettingsManager.getInstance().playlistTimeOffset != null){
                    now.plus(SettingsManager.getInstance().playlistTimeOffset);
                }
            }
            WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) AuthenticationService.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            android.view.Display screenDisplay = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
            int width = screenDisplay.getWidth();
            int height = screenDisplay.getHeight();

            View element = create(width,height);
            if (element != null){
                StartUpActivity.getInstance().setView(element);

                state = DisplayState.Created;
                if (contentState == DisplayContentState.Unknown){
                    contentState = DisplayContentState.Valid;
                }
            } else {
                destroyDisplayOnFail();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Creating display failed. "+getLoggingContentIdentificationString()+" "+e.toString());
        destroyDisplayOnFail();
    }
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling your `setView` method ???

Comment: @UttamPanchasara editted

Comment: your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and your inflating layout  `vs = (View) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);` both are same?

Comment: yes its the same @UttamPanchasara

Comment: so you are inflating that same layout ?

Comment: add directly in mainView

Comment: ok now we are adding it directly to the mainView, but there is no difference between adding it to the mainView over the layoutInflater or adding it to the mainView directly @UttamPanchasara

Comment: may be because you are inflating the same layout as `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: @UttamPanchasara so what do you suggest us to do now?

Comment: create another view and then add it to your rootview

Comment: You are talking about setting a bitmap but nowhere there is a bitmap in your code. Please don't confuse us like that and rephrase.

Comment: we gotta display more media things like not just pictures, so we have got a abstract class Display.java and a class ImageDisplay.java. The ImageDisplay implements a method wich preloads the picture in a bitmap, that is working fine. I'm sure, that the View element is correctly filled. @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

Don't use setContentView(element); in your setView method because you replace view of activity. Your rootLayout is a child view of R.layout.activity_main view which are replaced. That is why you don't see anything.

Comment: forget the setContentView(element), i forgot to delete it

Comment: what about adding the ImageView to the RelativeLayout? it doesnt show anything

Comment: try to call rootLayout.invalidate(); after you add view to it.